# Why is my BiSS C encoder not responding to register writes?

Tags: encoder

I am trying to write some data to a RLS BiSS C encoder. I'm able to get the single cycle data, so the connection is working and my clock timing seems to be correct. However, according to my interpretation of the [BiSS C Register Write Process](http://biss-interface.com/download/biss-an-11/), the encoder should respond with a 1 on the first ID LOCK bit after I send a start bit.

Here's a screenshot from a logic analyzer:
[image: A logic analyzer capture of an attempted register write]

The encoder doesn't seem to be setting *any* CDS bits, even when the standard suggests it should.

I've tried:

- Changing the MA clock frequency to the lowest allowable, and the middle of the allowable range
- Changing the number of clock cycles per BiSS Frame in case I was off by one or two.

Here's a zoomed in photo of a single cycle:
[image: Zoomed in BiSS Frame]

The frame seems to be valid and matches the datasheet of the encoder that I'm using (page 12 of [this PDF](https://www.rls.si/eng/fileuploader/download/download/?d=1&file=custom%2Fupload%2FBRD01_11.pdf)).

If I'm able to get valid SCD data and the logic analyzer software recognizes the CDM bits I'm setting, why isn't the encoder responding appropriately?

Comment: `encoder should respond with a 1 on the first ID LOCK bit` ... confirm that you are actually setting the correct bit ... data could be sent LSB first, or vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRC wasn't inverted, so the encoder wasn't responding to the write request.

However, the ID LOCK bits were all zero, which doesn't seem to be compliant with the standard, unless I'm interpreting things wrong.